# Как убрать ошибку кодировки? TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, кодировка

```
api = vk_requests.create_api(access_token='{мой access_token}') # create api
profiles = api.users.get() # get user info
username = profiles[0]['first_name']+' '+profiles[0]['last_name'] # get user name

data = 'name'+ username
data.encode('utf-8')
#print(sys.version_info) # get version
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://{название сайта}.net/check.php",data)
html = response.read().decode("utf-8") # set utf-8
print('Ваше имя: ' + html)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mainScript.py", line 26, in
 <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://{название сайта}.net/check.php",data)   File
 "c:\python34x\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "c:\python34x\lib\urllib\request.py", line 462, in open
    req = meth(req)   File "c:\python34x\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1113, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg) TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас data кодируется в utf-8 байты, а результат выбрасывается, надо в переменную записать

```
data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Сервер возвращает - [Ваше имя: ]

Comment: @UCharp ну это уже к данному вопросу точно не относится :) Но может стоит попробовать `data = 'name=' + urllib.request.quote(username)` вместо `data = 'name'+ username`

Answer (score 1):

Строки это неизменяемые объекты в Питоне. `data.encode('utf-8')` вызов не может изменить data—этот метод *возвращает* байты, которые у вас никак не используются.

Чтобы избавиться от TypeError вы должны байты, а не Unicode в urlopen() передать.